# Java GUI Thread not closing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, dispose, event-dispatch-thread

I have a plugin for an application containing a GUI (Swing) and is started as a thread. The GUI starts a thread that does some processing on a buttonevent, right after disposing itself. While processing, a dialog window functions as a logger. Everything works fine, the GUI and dialog window will close and the threads terminate, when calling `window.dispose()` after the processing finished.
Threads are started as Threads, not via SwingUtilities (I tried many times, but i just can't get that to work).

Basicly the entry class for the application:

```
public void calledByApplication(){
     RunnableClass.startGui(this);
}

public void doStuff(){         //GUI actually gets created here
     gui.setVisible(true);
}

public void calledWhenSaveButtonPressed(){
    //Process some stuff
    gui.dispose();             //works, thread terminates
}
```

RunnableClass (implements Runnable):

```
ApplicationEntryClass aec;

public RunnableClass(ApplicationEntryClass aec){
    this.aec = aec;
}

public void run(){
    aec.doStuff();
}

public static void startGui(ApplicationEntryClass aec){
    Thread guiThread = new Thread(new RunnableClass(aec));
    guiThread.start();
}
```

Gui Class:

```
public void calledWhenSaveButtonPressed(){
    aec.calledWhenSaveButtonPressed();
}

public void calledWhenCancelButtonPressed(){
    this.dispose();           //doesn't work
}
```

My problem:
When trying to dispose the GUI via button event (or the x with `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`), it closes, but the thread doesn't terminate. After looking at the stack i noticed, that the EventDispatchThread gets stuck on `EventDispatchThread.pumpEventForFilter(...)`.

I'm well aware, that the issue could be, that the thread doesn't get automatically destroyed. But since i'm new to threading i don't really know where to start troubleshooting. Any suggestions?

Edit: The dialog window is not the problem. Also, i can't use `System.exit()` or else the application calling the plugin will terminate.

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around this. Can you provide a *real* [mcve]. A small example that we actually can *compile and run* ourselves? Not your full code, just something that we can use to repro your specific issue?

Comment: So, you want to kill the event dispatching thread? Why?

Comment: I'm trying that at the moment, but i believe it will be hard to reproduce on way or another, since the plugin makes calls to an appserver... Also i removed everything but the entry class, the ui and the runnable and it seems to work.
I know that getting help that way is pretty hopeless, but i want more like a guide/hint/tipp, on how i can troubleshoot whether this is related to having 2 guis in different threads, or the EDT, etc. ...

Comment: One more Note: The whole thing was working great, the thread, that the processing happens in terminated fine. The Problem started, when i moved the gui into it's own thread.

Comment: @Rocco Not really. The EDT just doesn't kill itself for some reason.

Comment: What happens if you drop the RunnableClass and just replace `RunnableClass.startGui(this);` with `EventQueue.invokeLater(()->doStuff())`?

Comment: I ask this because I really don't understand why you create a new thread to show the window.

Comment: @Rocco same result. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Consider the possibility that you have some other resource than the Frame that is not disposed (e.g. a dialog)

Comment: @Rocco I need to have the whole plugin in an external thread because i need to make calls to the API from the plugin aswell as the processthread.
I make it more specific. The processthread is a plugin in itself that is included in the "gui plugin". When i use Threads, i can i.e. use an "export" function to export a file i want to open with the "gui plugin" if i don't use a Thread, i can't wait for the export to execute, since any .sleep() or .join() operations will freeze the Appserver, the other plugin is trying to access.

Comment: @Rocco Definetly no ui resources

Comment: @Rocco Yikes, I found it. I made the issue to .pack() the log dialog and then not showing it. I didn't know that this is an issue. Thank you very much, that just gave me the right idea.